# How to draw a circle with OpenGL(LWJGL specifically) using VBOs

Tags: java, lwjgl

I am currently learning LWJGL(LightWeight Java Game Library), the OpenGL-Java port, and am trying to figure out how to draw a circle using VBOs.

When I search for code samples concerning my problem (I search OpenGL b/c the syntax of OpenGL & LWJGL are quite similar), all I find is people using `glBegin(GL_QUADS)` and such, which I don't like due to its poor performance and its insufficiency. I know it uses thing like `Math.PI` and such(I've taken Geometry, the math is not the hard part in my opinion).

I want to know how I would get the X and Y values I receive from using `Math.cos` & `Math.sin` into the VBO, b/c when using `glDrawArrays`, you have to specify the number of vertices.

Comment: `Math.cos` and `Math.sin` don't return X and Y values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have a lot of this mixed up.  LWJGL and openGL really have nothing to do with this and whether you use `glDrawArrays` or `glBegin` doesn't matter.

There is no `drawCircle` function anywhere in LWJGL, you have to draw your circle using triangles, if you want to be more efficient a triangle fan is better.

Here is a method I wrote which gives you the verticies for a filled arc (specify 0 and 360 for `startingAngleDeg` and `endAngleDeg` for a full circle).

```
public static float[] getFilledArcVertexes(float x, float y, float r, double startingAngleDeg, double endAngleDeg, int slices) {
        if(startingAngleDeg < 0)
            Heatstroke.error("Starting angle cannot be smaller than 0");
        if(endAngleDeg >= 720)
            Heatstroke.error("End angle cannot be greater or equal to than 720");
        if(endAngleDeg < startingAngleDeg)
            Heatstroke.error("End angle cannot be smaller than starting angle");
        int radius = (int) r;

        double arcAngleLength = (endAngleDeg - startingAngleDeg) / 360f;

        float[] vertexes = new float[slices*6+6];

        double initAngle = Math.PI / 180f * startingAngleDeg;
        float prevXA = (float) Math.sin(initAngle) * radius;
        float prevYA = (float) Math.cos(initAngle) * radius;

        for(int arcIndex = 0; arcIndex < slices+1; arcIndex++) {
            double angle = Math.PI * 2 * ((float)arcIndex) / ((float)slices);
            angle += Math.PI / 180f;
            angle *= arcAngleLength;
            int index = arcIndex * 6;
            float xa = (float) Math.sin(angle) * radius;
            float ya = (float) Math.cos(angle) * radius;
            vertexes[index] = x;
            vertexes[index+1] = y;
            vertexes[index+2] = x+prevXA;
            vertexes[index+3] = y+prevYA;
            vertexes[index+4] = x+xa;
            vertexes[index+5] = y+ya;
            prevXA = xa;
            prevYA = ya;
        }

        return vertexes;
    }
```

This is a pretty badly coded method made by myself in  a rush.  Make sure you understand it before you use it however, here is a breakdown of how it works:

1. Work out the initial angle (only applies if drawing an arc)
2. Loop over every number from 0 to `slices`, this parameter is the level of detail you want your circle to have, higher means more triangles however once you reach a certain level no more detail will be added and will just eat up cpu time.
3. Work out the angle in radians
4. Use `Math.sin` and `Math.cos` to work out the x and y values for that particular point on the outside of the circle
5. Add the appropriate vertexes to the `vertexes` array

This will return an array of floats that should be used with `GL_TRIANGLES`, you could try improving it to use `GL_TRIANGLE_FAN`

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I figured I'd mix up some stuff, since I've only being learning this stuff for ~2 weeks. I did know that it had to be made with triangles(and I just learned what triangle fans are).

Answer (score 0):

//You Can use this small glBegin() code and convert into VBO

```
double k=0;
    glBegin(GL_POINTS);
    for(k=0;k<=360;k+=0.1){
    glVertex2f((float)(x+r*Math.cos(Math.toRadians(k))),(float)(y-r*Math.sin(Math.toRadians(k))));
    }
    glEnd();
```